# How to use yarn add/npm install with monorepos

Tags: node.js, typescript, git, npm, monorepo

I need to download a node package from a private monorepo in GitHub, similar to this:

```
monorepoProject
  --- subProjectA
  --- subProjectB
```

And both **subProjectA** and **subProjectB** are typescript projects, that looks like the diagram below:

```
subProjectB:
 --- dist
 --- src
     --- index.ts
     --- myCode.ts
 --- package.json
 --- README.md
 --- tsconfig.json
```

This is the project`s link:

```
https://github.com/company/monorepoProject
```

To clone via SSH:

```
git clone git@github.com:company/monorepoProject.git
```

I tried to use [gitpkg](https://gitpkg.vercel.app) like this:

```
yarn add 'https://gitpkg.now.sh/company/monorepoProject/subProjectB?commitHash123123'
```

but I had no success. What can I do to download a node package from a subdirectory in Github?

Answer (score 5):

Let's use my monorepo, https://github.com/codsen/codsen — a monorepo of bunch of npm packages — as an example.

In short, it depends what you mean by "need to download". Also, do you need script/UMD/IIFE or a ESM/CJS build.

**If you want to contribute**, clone whole monorepo on GitHub, work on the particular sub-package (`cd` into `packages/*` and use that package's npm scripts such as `test` etc). For example, you can see few people forked my monorepo. They would play around and sometimes raise a PR from their fork.

**If you want to consume one of the monorepo sub-programs**, theoretically, maintainers should publish it to npm and you'd consume it from npm, via normal `npm i` flow. So, you don't have to pluck the package out of monorepo at the first place.

If it's not possible to consume from `npm`, and you have a working monorepo, theoretically, you can symlink root of each package manually into your project's `node_modules`. That's dirty but it is possible. Snippet is like this: `ln -s /Users/roy/packages/detergent /Users/roy/packages/object-all-values-equal-to/node_modules/detergent` (here I symlink `detergent` into `object-all-values-equal-to` node_modules, so `detergent` could be consumed as a dependency).

Now, it's unlikely, but if somehow you really need to **pluck the program out of the monorepo**, let's say it hasn't been published to npm, maybe it's for internal use. In that case, check the licence, if it's permissive open source licence, you can git-clone the whole monorepo, copy-paste the files you need out of it into your project — just properly attribute the creator (typically, copy-paste their MIT licence under your MIT licence, within the same file and possibly mention what files are theirs) — make sure the licence is Open Source, for example, MIT (check in `package.json`). The challenge will be patching up missing imports but it can be done.

For example, I have [maintenance scripts](https://github.com/codsen/codsen/tree/main/ops/lect) - if you'd want to take them and use them in your monorepo, you'd have to copy-paste relevant files and attribute by storing my MIT licence along your licence.

If you need a monorepo-based package to **drive your web project**, normally you'd consume that package from npm and use bundlers such as webpack. In tiny projects, you might find it faster to grab the UMD/IIFE script, either directly from CDN's or save it as a local file. For example, I build, commit and npm-publish IIFE builds of non-CLI's, they're available from JSDelivr and others. For example, `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/detergent/dist/detergent.umd.js"></script>`.

Also, when you say "private monorepo" I'd first understand it as **closed-source project**, the "private packages" as npm [uses the term](https://www.npmjs.com/products). It doesn't affect the whole consumption matter, only privacy and legal aspects. But maybe you meant "personal monorepo" or "somebody's monorepo"?

If it's a really private monorepo, a truly private, closed-source corporate package, you'd need to set up credentials, see [npm page](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-private-packages).

Also, when you mentioned **GitPkg**. I checked it, it's strange. Let's take my monorepo as an example, let's say you wanted to grab `detergent` package from git. Well, bad news, I don't commit the build artifacts (`dist/`), I commit only source files, so something along the line of `npm install 'https://gitpkg.now.sh/codsen/codsen/packages/detergent?main'` is not possible because *detergent-the-program* comes from git-ignored (but not npm-ignored) `dist/` folder. But *jsDelivr* does pick up packages previously published to npm, for example, see https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/detergent?path=dist — notice the UMD and ESM builds, but they come from npm, that's not consuming from GitHub.

Comment: Thank you! The symlink tip worked great—built the sub-project in the monorepo, symlinked into external package's node_modules, everything just works! I tried to "pluck the program out of the monorepo" and ran into weird TypeScript issues so thank you for all these options!

Comment: @revelt You wrote this comment in april 2022, but in march 2022, so after one month you switched to using turbo. Why did you switch from npm?