# Using a single npm workspace/project within a forked monorepo?

Tags: npm, package.json, monorepo

One of our project's dependencies requires some additional modifications so that we can it. At first it was in its [own repository](https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-file-picker), but then the owner moved it into a [monorepo](https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-plugins) with a number of other projects.

I'm used to being able to run `npm i <github-url>#<git-hash>` and install forked repos but I'm not sure how to do this given that the project we are actually forking is within the `workspaces` section of [package.json](https://github.com/1stphorm/capacitor-plugins/blob/e4aa4dd7c641afb95cf985119f466ce5a8e0e55e/package.json#L5C1-L7):

```
"workspaces": [
  "packages/*"
],
```

What *seems* like it should work is that I should be able to do something like `npm i <repo> -w <workspace>`. But this doesn't work as it is meant for local development.

Just keeping notes here as I do my own research. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71833632/how-to-use-yarn-add-npm-install-with-monorepos) is asking something similar to what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like after doing some looking around online, the only way I've found to successfully do this seems to be picking of the two methods:

1. Create a forked version of the project with the root being just the subdirectory of the project you want.
2. Just create an internally forked version and forgo any formalities.